# How to close an Internet Explorer instance inside an Excel VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

I'm running an Excel VBA macro which opens a IE instance, extracts data from a URL and then is supposed to close the instance again.

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
' Do stuff...
' Clean up
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
```

I looked up that method and it is supposed to close the IE instance. However that does not work for me. 
The task manager confirms that the `iexplorer.exe` process is still running. If I run the macro several times a new instance is added and never closed.

How can I make the macro properly close the instance?

I'm using IE 8.0 and VBA 7.0 on this.

Comment: You appear to create two instances hence why one is left open.  you do an IE CreateObject, then IE GetObject.   you never close the first one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Sorceri statet correct in the comments, I have created two instances.
The following Code quits the instance without problems.

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
' Do stuff...
' Clean up
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
```

Interesting about the above (wrong) code is, that he indeed opens 2 instances, but does not close either of them at the end.