# VBA Macro to send WhatsApp custom message to multiple contacts

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a macro code below to send `whatsapp` message in column H to multiple contacts in Column A3:A10. However, the code below keep looping to send the same message to contact in cell A3 only.

How do I send the custom message to A4, A5 and etc.?

```
Sub msg_click()
On Error GoTo errorh:
mobileno = Selection.Value
Set myrange = Sheet1.Range("A3:A10")
rowno = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(mobileno, myrange, 0)
Message = Sheet1.Cells(rowno, 8).Value

Do Until Range("A3") = ""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="https://wa.me/" & mobileno & "?text=" & Message & ""
Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3) 'ok just one wait and sendkeys :v
SendKeys "~"
Loop
End
errorh:
Err.Clear
MsgBox "Select Proper Mobile Number "
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use `ActiveCell`. `For Each rng in myRange` is a better way to  loop.

Comment: Hi, if my code helped, please kindly mark it as answered and upvote. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that you are always checking only cell A3 in your loop. And you are performing offset always to the same cell A1. As in comment by BigBen it is indeed better practice to use for each rig in myRange. If you want a simple hack, you should modify it to following.

```
Sub msg_click()

Range("A3").Activate
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="https://wa.me/" & ActiveCell.Value & "?text=" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Text
Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3) 'ok just one wait and sendkeys :v
SendKeys "~"

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop
End

End Sub
```

Not the best practice but I guess you are starting.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kamil, it works for me. Is there any code we can add to close the browser tab? Because after the macro above executed, browser will leave many opened tabs. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @JiaLiang I am happy it worked for you. Would you mind also upvoting my answer (clicking on arrow above 0)? It is possible [How to close an Internet Explorer instance inside an Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624518/how-to-close-an-internet-explorer-instance-inside-an-excel-vba). However, it looks like there is time for you to get interested in General Purpose Languages like Python for example (simple, popular, powerful). Thing you have done in VBA is so much easier in Python (and I suppose many others) and you have control over entire environment i.e. list, msg, browsers etc.

Comment: I have hitting on arrow above, however i received the message Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Thank for your recommendation on Python. Will look into it.